# calling method from onDraw blows app

Tags: android, graphics2d

I have the following code that blows the app. Methods like drawLine work fine if they are directly inside "onDraw" but not if placed outside in a separate method as shown below. Does anyone have any idea what's wrong? The version with the method **compiles ok** but the app crashes when started.

Many thanks
   Roberto

```
public class Painter extends View {

private static Canvas canvas;
private static Paint paintG = null;
public static int screenW; // screen width
public static int screenH; // screen height

private String tag = "Painter";

public Painter(Context context) {
    super(context);
    readDrawingData(); 
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    screenW = canvas.getWidth(); // screen width
    screenH = canvas.getHeight(); // screen height
    Rect allScreen = new Rect(0, 0, screenW, screenH);

    // works OK
    paintG = new Paint();
    paintG.setAntiAlias(true);
    paintG.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paintG.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paintG.setColor(0xFFf7f9d2);
    canvas.drawRect(allScreen, paintG);

    // paint circle/oval - works OK
    double R = ((screenW > screenH) ? screenH : screenW) / 2 - 100;
    double Z = R + 20;
    double X = screenW /2;
    double Y = screenH /2;
    RectF oval1 = new RectF(Math.round(X-R), Math.round(Y-R), 
                            Math.round(X+R), Math.round(Y+R));
    paintG.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paintG.setColor(0xffff0000);
    canvas.drawOval(oval1, paintG);

    // this code works OK here
    paintG.setColor(0xffff0000);
    if (i > 0) {
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
            canvas.drawLine(x1[j], y1[j], x2[j], y2[j], paintG);
        }
    }

// calling this will crash app
paintDrawing();

}

// ************************************************************
void paintDrawing() {
    // PROBLEM: same code as above - causes app to crash...
    // when outside onDraw
    paintG.setColor(0xffff0000);
    if (i > 0) {
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
        canvas.drawLine(x1[j], y1[j], x2[j], y2[j], paintG);
    }
}
// ************************************************************
```

}

Comment: lack of basic java knowledge ( variable scopes) and -1 for posting NPE related question

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please note that variables such as **i** etc are declared in the original file. This code is just a fragment!

Comment: what is a field? what is a local variable? do you know the differences? ... also phrase "app crash" is not used by real programmers (becuase it is too broad)

Comment: `i` is not the problem, `canvas` is

Comment: comment of Selvin is not correct. If I comment out drawLine and paintG the app works. drawLine and paintG are declared as static and global!

Comment: remove your global `canvas` and you will see the problem

Comment: seems like it is even worst case ... it is not duplicate of "What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?" but rather : [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: paintG and canvas are not null. in the method I added  **if(canvas == null) Log.i(tag, 'canvas is null');** same for paintG and both do not produce a log!

Comment: oh? then where do you set canvas?

Comment: then what exception are you getting and where(which line - not number please just cite whole line)?

Comment: *paintG and canvas are not null* yeah, sure .... http://ideone.com/qemrE3

Comment: sorry - I really missed to assign the global values. Many thanks.

Comment: If you debugged your app like @Selvin suggested you wouldn't have